# Best way to organise back end (Node) processes and front end (Vue / Nuxt) that uses part of these processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a few tiny node apps doing some basic stuff like checking things and filling my DB (triggered by CRON). In my Nuxt app I will need to use part of what is insinde these Node apps. What is the best way to organise it, do I keep them separated or do I fuse them with my Nuxt app ? Do I copy what I need from these node apps and adapt it in Nuxt, do I use the serverside middlewares to add those node apps inside my Nuxt project or do I create my Nuxt app with express and I use /server/index.js to add my node apps there in some way ?

Let's take an example. You have a node app that check very hour some data and fill a DB. In the Nuxt app you have a page showing the content of the DB but you want first to be sure that nothing new has to be added in the DB since the last hour. The code I would have to run in th every Nuxt page is the same code as the Node app (check and fill the DB). It looks a bit stupid (and hard to maintain and update) to have twice the same code at two places. But I 'm not sure how would I have this node app running every hour in my Nuxt app. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is a pretty high level question. In general, decoupling the front and back ends is optimal, because then your backend can serve other front ends (i.e., mobile and desktop).

In terms of having same code in two places, this is a scenario where you would develop a microservice to handle the change detection for both front and back ends. This allows you to follow DRY (do not repeat yourself). In node, understanding microservices is essential for this reason.

Comment: All this is still very new to me but I understand what you say. I will learn more about microservices, it looks like the way to go. If I understand well, I will be able to launch my micro service from my server / CRON and from my Nuxt app. The microservice will detect from where comes the request and act differently ...? I didn't realized microservices were such an important part in Node. Although it may not seem so, your answer has been very valuable !

Comment: That sounds like an appropriate configuration. When you build it, try editing this question with your code included and I will give some feedback. 

Microservices are not always necessary in Node, depending on the use case. But many times that is the most sensible approach for handling situations where more than one component requires the same functionality. An example from my app is that I use the Axios HTTP handler, and instead of initializing Axios in each component I built an Axios microservice that can serve each component, thus reducing my Axios instances to 1.I will post some steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a control flow that may help your thinking about designing this CRON microservice. There are many ways to do this, and this may not be the best approach, but I think it will work for your use case.

1. Have a `services` directory in your server (can also be called `middleware`).
2. Include a `cron.js` file that contains the logic for the task runner.
3. Within `cron.js`, issue a scheduled response from node to Vue, such as a JSON keyword like `res.JSON({message: 'checkNewData'})`. This will be something called a "server sent event". A server sent event is simply an event that happens autonomously on a defined schedule within node environment.
4. In Vue, at the root level `App.vue`, use the `created()` hook to register an event listener that will listen for the server sent `"checkNewData"` JSON object. When this event listener hears the JSON response, it should trigger Vue to check the appropriate component, package up any new data, and send it down to the DB in a `post` or `put` http call, depending on whether you're adding new data, or replacing the old with the new.

This configuration would give you a closed-loop system for automatic updates. The next challenge would be making this operation client-specific, but that is something to worry about once you got this working. Again, others may have a different approach to this, but this is how I would handle the flow.

Comment: Sure thing, let me know if you have any questions